# Open file I/O memory management in python

Tags: python, file, memory, io

I'm writing a script which has a huge list of weather observations. For each weather observation in the list, the code opens a weather radar file for that time. It then pulls out some data and moves onto the next line/observation.

To be safe with the memory, I want to close the weather radar file when I move onto the next line. Here is a simplified version of what I do:

```
    synop = open(filename).read().splitlines()
    synop.close()
```

The first line is fine and I can do stuff later with synop just fine. Trying to close synop causes a problem though as it is `type = list`.

Is there an alternate way to close the file I am accessing? Or does python automatically close the file after the first line of code?

I will be running this on approx. 4.5m files so I need good memory management!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not keeping the `file` object. Python will close the file for you after the first line, but thats not correct nor pythonic, since it's not explicit.

One correct way is to keep the `file` object, like this:

```
f = open(filename)
synop = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
```

But the best way is to use `context management`

```
with open(filename) as f:
    synop = f.read().splitlines()
```

Python will close file for you as soon this scope ends.